# Data mess in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been struggling with this problem for days.

The problem is that my angular directive is messing with my data model.

For simplicity, I have created a simple example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/xxy4vh3v/

```
angular.module('vt.directives', [])
    .directive('personType', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            personType: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="{{pClass}}" style="height: 80px; width: 200px">Class: {{pClass}}<br>Type: {{personType}}</div>',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.personType);
            scope.pClass = scope.personType == 'male' ? 'male-class' : 'female-class';
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I click on one of the add buttons, it adds one more person to the data model. The problem is that the directive is not using the right data values. If you click on 'Add Anne', the data looks right "outside" the directive, but not "inside". It should return the right class name (and color) based on the data, but added females is shown as blue (male).

And no matter how many or which buttons you click only the first two is blue. The rest is red.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using track by wrong because you were using unshift, and the actual index positions of your elements was changing. Try adding a unique id to each object you insert into the array and tracking by that instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/kku170cm/

Here's the track by that works:

```
<div style="float: left; height: 140px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin-bottom: 20px;" ng-repeat="p in data.persons">
```